# Compare 2 arrays and distinguish same values in same position and same values in different positions in Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, logic

**I have hit a wall** (not literally) **and need assistance.  I am very new to Java so need to keep this basic to remain at my skill level.**

I have two Color[] arrays that contain 3 random colors. **I am trying to identify colors in the same position and colors that are the same but in different positions in the array.**

This is the same logic for those familiar with the scoring of Mastermind.

**Example:**

`answerColors[]{Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Blue}`

`userColors[]{Color.Yellow,Color.Blue,Color.Red}`

Results should display:

```
same color/position = 2 (this would be the Blue at [1])

same color/ different position = 1 (this would be the Red)
```

**Note:**

Because answerColors[1] == userColors[1], state that this is in the correct position, and do not state a Incorrect Position for userColors[1].

**Example 2:**

`answerColors[]{Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue}`

`userColors[]{Color.Yellow,Color.Blue,Color.Red}`

Results should display:

`same color/position = 1 (this would be the Yellow at [0])`
  `same color/ different position = 1 (this would be the Blue)`

```
//How will the poster distingush the difference between (Same Color, Correct Position) and (Same Color, **Different** Position)?
```

I have seen a lot of posts that answer this kind of question, but none that address the state {Same Color, Different Position} when comparing two arrays, and stopping the same part of an array from being scanned twice. (Examples above with explanations. #1 is the most helpful.)

here is my code that is not working....results should be:

```
same color/same position = 2
same color/different position = 1
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

```
public void createScoreArray() {  // creates the array for     determining the values for the score panel (2 = same color/same position; 6 = not same color/same position; 1 = same color/different position ignoring those already in same color/same position
    answerColors[]{Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Blue};
    userColor[]{Color.Yellow, Color.Blue, Color.Red};
    int j = 0;
    scoreNumCheck = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < answerColors.length; i++) {  // checking same color same position
        if (answerColors[i] == userColor[j]) {
            scoreNumCheck[i] = 2;
            System.out.println(scoreNumCheck[i]);
            j++;
         System.out.println("++++++++++++Score Pegs: " + Arrays.toString(scoreNumCheck));
        } else if (answerColors[i] != userColor[j]) {
            scoreNumCheck[i] = 6;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("--------- " + Arrays.toString(scoreNumCheck));


    }
    System.out.println("++++++++++++Score Pegs: " + Arrays.toString(scoreNumCheck));
    for (int s = 0; s < scoreNumCheck.length; s++) {
        if (scoreNumCheck[s] != 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < answerColors.length; i++) {
                for (int u = 0; u < userColor.length; u++) {
                    if (userColor[u] == (answerColors[i])) {
                        scoreNumCheck[6] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("2.  ++++++++++++Score Pegs: " + Arrays.toString(scoreNumCheck));
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are already looping through all of the answers, consider looping again when the cards are not equal through all of the users answer and see if they match current answer

Answer (score 1):

Please attempt to use methods to check if the wording of the question is understandable to the readers. (Try getting a friend to read it.) I could not understand the code. I attempted to remake the code.

```
package StackOverflowAnswers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class StackOverflow53568488 {
    Color[] answerColors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE};
    Color[] userColors = {Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.RED}; //There is no Color.Red, there is Color.RED and Color.red.
    int [] scoreNumCheck;
    public void createScoreArray() {  
 // creates the array for determining the values for the score panel 
 //(2 = same color/same position; 
 // 6 = not same color/same position; 
 // 1 = same color/different position ignoring those already in same color/same position

        scoreNumCheck = new int[3];

        LinkedList <Integer> Results = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
        //You should only be able to get a size of 3 in this LinkedList

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            if (answerColors[i] == userColors[i]){
                Results.add(2);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                if(answerColors[i] == userColors[j]){ // Try drawing this stuff out...
                    Results.add(1); // add scores to Results
                }
            }
        }
        while (Results.size() < 3){
            Results.add(6); // Use the fact that you should always get a size of 3 in Results to be able to add 6 until that condition is satisfied.
        }
        //I failed to understand how you printed the answers.


        //
    }
}
```